# JQGrid grid cannot not refresh normally and method GridUnload seems that work unexpectedly

Tags: jquery, jqplot

An unexpected issue occurred When refreshing the existed JQGrid: The grid displays no problem for the first time, and then user apply new data to grid, the header and data table, and pager of grid disappears:

```
    $("#grid").GridUnload();

    grid = jQuery("#grid").jqGrid({
        data : response.list,
        datatype : "local",
        colNames : columnNames,
        colModel : [ {
            name : 'column1',
            index : 'column1',
            width : 100,
            sorttype : 'text'
        }, {
            name : 'column2',
            index : 'column2',
            width : 100,
            sorttype : 'text'
        }, {
            name : 'column3',
            index : 'column3',
            width : 100,
            sorttype : 'text'
        }, {
            name : 'column4',
            index : 'column4',
            width : 100,
            sorttype : 'text'
        } ],
        rowNum : 30,
        width : $("#grid").width(),
        height : $("#grid").height(),
        rowList : [ 30, 100, 150 ],
        pager : "#gridPage",
        sortname : 'column1',
        viewrecords : true,
        sortorder : "desc",
        shrinkToFit : false,
        rownumbers : true,
        altRows : true,
        caption : "Sample Grid",
    });

    jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('navGrid', "#gridPage", {
        edit : false,
        add : false,
        del : false,
        search : false,
        refresh : false
    });

    jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
        useColSpanStyle : true,
        groupHeaders : [ {
            startColumnName : 'column1',
            numberOfColumns : 2,
            titleText : 'MergedColumn1'
        }, {
            startColumnName : 'column3',
            numberOfColumns : 2,
            titleText : 'MergedColumn2'
        } ]
    });
```

Here, as you can see, before create a new JQGrid grid I use method '`$("#grid").GridUnload();`' to clear it.

I'm hardly figure it out and had no idea what makes it happen? Can anybody give me help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying for several times, I solved this issue. For my case, if grid need to have fixed width and height, and display horizontal scroll bar when its columns too many, just like following way to set the jqGrid:

```
grid= jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid({
    width : 1000,
    height: 800,
    shrinkToFit: false,
});
```

The most important thing that makes sure the grid working no problem is that you SHOULD add THML configuration 'align="center"' to the table that the grid attaches.

```
<table id="grid_id" align="center"></table>
```

I don't know why this solves it, but anyway, It works.